# Adding BY column in query function

Tags: google-sheets

In google sheets, whenever I try to return the column BY using =QUERY() it identifies it not as a column, but as a command. How would I return that specific column using this formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
=QUERY(BX:BY,"select BX, `BY`")
```

More info here:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Identifiers

And posiible solution:

```
=QUERY({BX:BY},"select Col1, Col2")
```